# graph of half-normal plots residuals in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, glm

I am trying to make the graph presented below for the residuals in the half-normal plot in ggplot2.
[image]

However, I am facing an error entitled Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by`fortify ()`, not an S3 object with class hnp.

The data can be seen below.

```
library(hnp)
Stones <- c(rep("Stone1",1), rep("Stone2",1), rep("Stone3",1))
treat <- c(rep("T6",9), rep("T7",9), rep("T8",9), 
           rep("T10",9), rep("T11",9),
           rep("T12",9),rep("T14",9),rep("T15",9),
           rep("T16",9))
Samples <- c(rep("SampleI",3), rep("SampleF",3), rep("SampleR",3))
Count <- c(3,3,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,6,
           1,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,4,4,1,3,2,5,0,0,0,3,4,4,5,1,2,0,0,0,
           4,4,6,1,2,1,0,0,0,4,6,4,2,3,1,0,0,0,3,2,2,1,0,5,0,1,0)
Total <- c(rep("6", 81))
dados <- data.frame(treat, Stones, Samples, Count, Total);dados
dados$treat = as.factor(dados$treat)
dados$Samples = as.factor(dados$Samples)
dados$Total = as.numeric(dados$Total)
dados$Prop = dados$Count/dados$Total
dados16 = dados[dados$treat=="T16",];dados16`
```

The model adjustment is shown below.

```
resp16 <-cbind(dados16$Count,dados16$Total - dados16$Count); resp16
m16 <- glm(resp16 ~ Samples,
           data = dados16,
           family = quasibinomial)

Graph16=hnp(m16, xlab = 'Percentil da N(0,1)', ylab = 'Resíduos', 
    main = 'Gráfico Normal de Probabilidades')
```

The error is here.

```
ggplot(data = Graph16)
Erro: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class hnp
```

Comment: Could you mention somewhere in your post from what package the `hnp()` function is?

Comment: Ok @teunbrand!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error indicates, ggplot2 expects a `data.frame` object or an object for which a `fortify()` S3 method has been written. The `hnp` class object doesn't have a fortify method, so probably our best option is to get the data out of the `Graph16` object and put it in a dataframe ourselves before plotting. Example below assumes the `Graph16` object is the same one produced from your code.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = Graph16$x,
  lower = Graph16$lower,
  median = Graph16$median,
  upper = Graph16$upper,
  residuals = Graph16$residuals
)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
              alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = residuals)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = median))
```

[image]